# Why printf with %.2g doesn't show two digits after the dot?

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%.2g %.2f\n", 2.925, 2.925);
}
```

I think that the right output should be:

```
2.93 2.93
```

Now, the output is the following:

```
2.9 2.92
```

There are two misunderstandings:

1. Why '%.2g' doesn't show the two digits after dot?
2. Why is the rounding off?

Comment: `2.925` is `2.92499999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875` exact. So rounding down is correct.

Comment: what about the first?

Answer (score 6):

## 1. Why is there different number of digits?

Precision field in `printf` conversion specification is different for `f` and `g` conversions. From standard (C17 draft, 7.21.6 Formatted input/output functions):

> - An optional *precision* that gives the minimum number of digits to appear for the d, i, o, u, x, and X conversions, **the number of digits to appear after the decimal-point character for a, A, e, E, f, and F conversions, the maximum number of significant digits for the g and G conversions**, ...

So with `f`, precision only specifies number of *digits after the decimal point*, but with `g` it is the maximum number of *all digits*.

## 2. Why does the number round down?

When you use floating point number in source code, it needs to be converted from decimal form to binary form during compilation. Decimal number `2.925` cannot be converted to binary form exactly with the limited precision of your `double` type, and value is slightly less (`2.92499999999999982236...`). When rounded to 2 decimal digits, nearest value is `2.92`.